# NextJS getServerSideProps not always executing on AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

When clicking through the app, the page props are passed to the page component sometimes but not always. It seems as though the `getServerSideProps` function isn't always being called as when the error happens no props are passed at all. This occurs when quickly navigating between pages.

I've tried simplifying the `getServerSideProps` to remove all API calls and just pass a hardcoded value but the error persists. I've also tried changing the nextJS version that is used to no avail. Locally it runs without issue and the log messages show that the function is called every time. The logs on Amplify only have the messages when the error didn't occur.

Currently using NextJs - 13.1.6

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We’ve been experiencing the same  thing. As a workaround, we have been using router.push(“page”) instead of NextJs links. This of course comes with the disadvantage that pages are not being prefetched and some other navigation feature would not work. The workaround suggests that it might be something to do with prefetching on some event handling logic for nextjs’ link component.